# Mongoose updating all nested fields to null on findByIdAndUpdate()

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to save a document in `MongoDB` using `Mongoose` and I don't want it to store the values not supplied as `null` or `[]` when i `findByIdAndUpdate()`.

P.S. I am storing everything in nested schemas.

```
{ 
   personalInformation:{ 
     name: { first: 'Nithin', last: null, middle: null },
     email: 'nithin@exam.com',
     phone: null
     location: { previous: [Array], current: null },
     dateOfBirth: null 
   },
   .
   .
}
```

Even though the value is not supplied while saving i get `null` on the database.

How do i overcome this?

My schema declaration is similar to this [Mongoose, findByIdAndUpdate sets nested schemas to null on update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858771/mongoose-findbyidandupdate-sets-nested-schemas-to-null-on-update) but i have not set any defaults.

Comment: By trimming the empty or null values out of `req.body`. That's your problem ( aside from using static form posts  that is. Surprised people are still doing that ). Or take the hint and actually have a JavaScript function handle the post and clean up the data before you even send it to the server. Many ways to do this.

Comment: @NeilLunn, How do i do that? `jQuery`?.

I'm using basic `POST` in my `ejs` form to submit it